# How to add javascript into php?

Tags: javascript, php

**Here is my js code**

```
<script>
function myform() {
    var n = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (n == "") {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
        return false;
    }
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter valid name";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

*How to write this js code into php*

**m trying all code in echo but not working plz help**

**after php echo using**

```
    echo'<script>
function myform() {
    var n = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (n == "") {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
        return false;
    }
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter valid name";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>';
```

thankyou

Comment: try to put it in a variable and echo that variable

Comment: pls do not do this..

Comment: I thought this seemed familiar... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591535/plz-help-how-to-write-js-code-into-php-code

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, you can just echo a `<script>` tag with JavaScript inside it, but you have to be careful about quotation marks (which works with your example, you have single-quoted the HTML and then used double-quotes inside the JavaScript). If your script is not working, it would be because you don't have the `<?php` frontmatter that every PHP script needs:

```php
<?php
echo '<script>
function myform() {
    var n = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (n == "") {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
        return false;
    }
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter valid name";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>';
```

This is functional but I would strongly recommend splitting the JavaScript off into a separate JS file and then referencing that file's location via the `src` attribute of the `script` tag. That will be far more maintainable in the future (and has the added benefit of working around quotation problems). So like

```php
<?php
echo '<script src="script.js"></script>'
```

and in script.js:

```js
function myform() {
    var n = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (n == "") {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
        return false;
    }
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter valid name";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want hide this js from client whos trying to view page source  thats why m trying to do php in js code

Comment: That is impossible. Your PHP will still print to the HTML page and be visible. You cannot execute arbitrary, invisible JavaScript on a user's machine; that would be a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript and PHP is correct. However, you need something to trigger the JavaScript function. In your case, for example you can add a button that triggers the JavaScript upon clicking.

```
<button onclick="myform();">Run</button>
```

Here is a working sample of your code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="name" value=""/>
<button onclick="myform();">
Run
</button>
Username: <span id="username">click run!</span>
```

JS

```
function myform() {
    var n = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (n == "") {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
        return false;
}
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Please enter valid name";
        return false;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1j0wxmk/

Comment: i want hide this js from client whos trying to view page source thats why m trying to do php in js code

Comment: It will still show up in view page source even if you echo it using PHP. @Akki

Comment: then how to hide this js file from client user

Comment: You can't hide it because JS is client-side unlike PHP which is server-side. If you really wanted to, you can minify it to make it harder to read or understand. https://javascript-minifier.com/